# iOS MVC - How to pass data from model to controller?

Tags: objective-c, ios, model-view-controller

I did quite a bit of research on this, but I am having a mental block about my problem. I am working on Objective-C for an iOS app

Here's my set up:

1. The view controller gets a text from the view (user input), and passes that text to the MethodA of the model.
2. The MethodA in model works on the input text and gets an output (e.g. searches google for that text). It does the search using dispatch_async method which calls the selector to MethodB within model.
3. MethodB parses the output and puts all the results into a NSMutableArray
4. **My Question Here:** how do I pass that NSMutableArray back to view controller so I can show it on the view?

Sorry, if the answer to my question is very simple/obvious. I am new to Objective-C

Comment: Are you using Core Data? I am not sure I personally fully understand your question. What is MethodB that's parsing the output?

Comment: Sorry, my question was unclear. Method A calls a web service using dispatch_async. The selector from dispatch_async calls Method B upon completion that gets the raw data (NSData). Method B parses the JSON reply from the NSData and puts those results into NSMutableArray. I am not using Core Data. Is Core Data a better way to implement this?

Comment: MethodA and MethodB are just methods inside the view controller?

Comment: No, they are inside the Model class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess passing along a delegate-object that respoons to a selector-method and calling this method with the processed data will be a good way to achieve the loosley coupled structure your program deserves. Are you familiar with this concept, or shall I dig up some code-samples for you?

---

**UPDATE: Code samples**

So, I would probably use the calling class, say `MyViewController`, to implement the callbackMethod, `myCallbackMethod` as follows:

```
-(void) myCallbakcMethod: NSMutableArray* array {
    //DoWhatever with the returned data
}
```

The point is to get the result passed back to this method when the computation is finished.
So in your `MyViewController` where you call `MethodA` you pass along a reference to the delegate to handle the result, namly `self`.

```
//From this:
[MyModel methodA:param1]
//To:
[MyModel methodA:param1:self]
```

`MyModel`s `methodA` and `methodB` would need to add a parameter `(id)delegate` and pass that along between the calls.

In `methodB` where the data `myArray` is ready, do the following call:

```
    if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myCallbackMethod:)]])
        [observer performSelector:@selector(myCallbackMethod:) withObject:myArray];
```

Comment: I think that's exactly what I am trying to implement (wasn't sure if that was possible until I saw your response). Code-samples will definitely help me. Thanks!

Comment: This is great! That's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 7):

Any time I want to do async processing and that stuff needs to get back into the UI somewhere,  I do one of two things:

```
1. Use NSNotification to tell anyone who cares that the work is complete
2. Use a delegate property on the worker and a @protocol
```

## 1 NSNotification

The model object should document in it's .h file that it fires notifications when certain things happen; such as when a portion of the model has been updated. When the ViewController initializes the model object, have it set itself up as an observer of the documented notification, and implement a callback which updates the UI.

## 2 delegation and @protocol

Create a @protocol such as `@protocol FooModelUpdateDelegate` with a method properly named such as `fooObjectDidUpdate:(Foo *)object;`, and then the model class has a delegate property as `id<FooModelUpdateDelegate> updateDelegate` and the ViewController sets itself as that delegate, and I'm sure you can figure out the rest.

Comment: Just to add to this, blocks are an even better way IMO these days.

Answer (score 2):

In your view controller:

```
    // your controller code
    ...
    [myModel getSearchResult:searchKeyword receiver:self action:@selector(responseReceived:)];
}

- (void)responseReceived:(MyModel *)model
{   
    NSArray *searchResult = model.searchResult; 
    [model release], model = nil;
    // some view actions, for instance update your table view
    ...
}
```

In your model:

```
...
- (id)getSearchResult:(NSString *)searchKeyword receiver:(id)aReceiver action:(SEL)receiverAction {
    self.receiver = aReceiver;
    self.action = receiverAction;
    // some async actions
}
```

In async response receiver:

```
    ...
    [self.receiver performSelector:self.action withObject:self];
}
```

Comment: where do you handle http errors then? may i have a more complete example? thanks :)

Comment: Using AFNetworking can save much time. It uses blocks instead of selectors. https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/master/Example/Classes

Comment: Thanks! This is what i m using. Then I moved AFNetworking calls into model data, then wrapped it again. Within the blocks, originally i fired notifications...now i changed to calls to success and failure blocks by adding blocks to the wrapper methods. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your description it sounds like your "model" class is doing more than it should.  In this case it's doing at least some of the work of your controller.  My suggestion would be to fold methodA and methodB into the view controller (or another controller class).  Method B could still set the NSMutableArray property of "model" instance, if that's essential (or skip that step if it's not).

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)methodA {
    NSMutableArray *someArray = ...
    [self methodB:someArray];
}

-(void)methodB:(NSMutableArray*)array {
    NSLog(@"%@", array);
    // do something with the array, like update the view
}
```

But if both are methods inside the view controller why not just update the view inside the method instead of passing it to another method?

Comment: That's what my initial code was like. I did all this within my ViewController. But I keep reading that Model should be responsible in dealing with the data, especially handling the logic, so that's why I wanted to implement the similar functionality in the Model. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Not necessarily. It's OK to deal with a bit of data in your view controller. But if you're looking at a lot, then use a delegate method to communicate back to your view controller from the model. You may also look at using blocks, these are fantastic.

Comment: Agree on blocks being fantastic. I use them in dispatch_async and they are quite simple to use. I should experiment on doing the same for passing data from Model back to another controller.