# How to pass data between modal view controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode

This is a noob question.what i want is to pass data from my QuizViewcontroller to QuizModalViewController.i was successful in creating a normal modal view controller but having problem when passing data between the two..below is my code.

**QuizViewController**

```
-(IBAction)button3Clicked:(id)sender
{
  QuizModalViewController *mvid=[[QuizModalViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"QuizModalViewController" bundle:nil];
mvid.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:mvid animated:YES];
}
```

**QuizModalViewController**

```
- (IBAction)goBackToView
{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
//[controller loadQuestion:currentQuestionIndex+1];
}
```

Comment: For passing data to "QuizModalViewController" you need to either create property in "QuizModalViewController" class or need to create public method

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS MVC - How to pass data from model to controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388888/ios-mvc-how-to-pass-data-from-model-to-controller)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016680/how-many-ways-to-pass-share-data-b-w-view-controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)button3Clicked:(id)sender
{
  QuizModalViewController *mvid=[[QuizModalViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"QuizModalViewController" bundle:nil];
mvid.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
mvid.theDataYouWantToPass = theData; // this is how you do it
[self presentModalViewController:mvid animated:YES];
}
```

Note that `theDataYouWantToPass` must be a property declared in the `QuizModalViewController.h` file.

Comment: This is the best way to do it.

Comment: `@property (nonatomic) NSInteger myInteger;`

Comment: OMG. I couldn't figure out why this wasn't working, and your note at the end reminded that I made the properties private by placing them in the implementation file. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the -(void)prepareForSegue:... - Method to share data between controllers.

For Example:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Your_Identifier"]) {

     TestViewController *controller = [segue destinationViewController];

     NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"",nil];

     controller.objectInTestViewController = array;

   }
}
```

Hope this helps someone....

Comment: I don't think `prepareForSegue` gets fired when using `presentModalViewController` since it's a programmatic way of doing a storyboard segue.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `QuizModalViewController` available at class scope instead of using a local variable.
Then in the `goBackToView:` you can access the controller's content prior to dismissing it.

By the way: in your code you're leaking `mvid`. Release it after presenting it modally.

Comment: could u gimme a small example

Comment: You should be able to find enough examples on SO, like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706281/pass-data-back-to-the-previous-controller or there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788294/how-to-access-to-parentviewcontroller-after-presentmodalviewcontroller

Comment: The question is pretty much how to pass the data TO modal view controller, not how to get it from it. So delegation is not the answer here. Custom init methods or properties is.

Comment: He might not be leaking since he's probably using ARC